# Failed to start ansibled.service: Unit not found

Tags: ansible, vagrant, centos7

I couldn't start my ansible server installed in Centos/7 yet the installation works properly, any help plz

```
[vagrant@ansible-server ~]$ sudo systemctl status ansibled

Unit ansibled.service could not be found.

[vagrant@ansible-server ~]$ sudo systemctl start ansibled

Failed to start ansibled.service: Unit not found.
```

Comment: ansible is not a service, there is no `ansibled`. just use `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible is not a Linux system Service. The command you are using is use for any service which is install on the linux. Just use Ansible command to run your playbook or adhoc command.